# How Erlang is better than other language in doing concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, programming-languages

I don't understand why erlang itself is great with concurrency

Is there anyway other language such as C# could be as great as erlang if we do some trick?

Or it is the very specific language feature of erlang that most language don't have?

Could we write C to be like erlang?

Comment: SO is not the place for such a question. You can find on the net many debates and presentations about this topic. Let's say that Erlang propose a model for concurrency and implement it natively.

Answer (score 2):

One Major property of Erlang is that it was built from the ground up to be a concurrent language.  Erlang supports hundreds of thousands of lightweight processes in a single virtual machine. Because Erlang's processes are completely independent of OS processes they are very lightweight, with low overhead per-process. Thus when using Erlang for concurrent oriented programming you get alot of advantages out of the box.

- Fast process creation/destruction
- Ability to support millions of concurrent processes with largely unchanged characteristics.
- Fast asynchronous message passing.
- Copying message-passing semantics (share-nothing concurrency).
- Process monitoring.
- Selective message reception.

This Erlang style concurrency is not impossible to do in C, but it would be hard to do it. Read [this blog](http://ulf.wiger.net/weblog/2008/02/06/what-is-erlang-style-concurrency/) for more information on Erlang style concurrency

Comment: [this is just flat out wrong if for no other reason that the Erlang VM that implements the light weight processes is implemented in C](https://www.openhub.net/p/erlang/analyses/latest/languages_summary)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Almost every high-level language is implemented in C but it doesn't mean you can use all high-level features in C. There are twenty years of development, experience, and ingenuity behind light-weight process implementation in Erlang. If you would try it in C you will end up with error prone implementation of half of Erlang. In short, you are wrong.

Comment: so only the authors of Erlang can get it "right", I respect your opinion on Erlang highly, but I think this is just FUD. Granted if you do not know what you are doing you will fail, but if you understand the problem it is completely feasible to do, just as the authors of Erlang have proven. C++ started as a "high-level" pre-processor for C. Simple googling shows that there is plenty of work implementing lightweight processes in C and other languages, even in Java. *In short, "if you would try it in C you will end up with error prone implementation of half of Erlang.", is you spreading FUD.*

Comment: It is not that itis just the authors of Erlang can get it "right" it is just that Erlang is one of the few languages where concurrency and fault-tolerance are fundamental from the bottom up and not added on later as a library. this affects *EVERYTHING* in the implementation.